# HTTP request withing email body

Tags: html, email, url, webserver

Using src html and url image from webserver, can the server get the message-id from the email header?

Or, is it possible for an URL to only work with a particular email message?

Ben

Comment: what html? what API? there's more than just ONE api in the universe.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I'm asking if it's possible, say using REST API. The url is used in the email message body to display a picture.

Comment: how should we know? `rest` isn't an API. it's a communications SPECIFICATION. API's can **IMPLEMENT** REST semantics, but saying "rest" is an api is like saying "this chunk of alumimum is a ferrari".

Comment: I did not say REST is an API, I mentioned it as architectural style...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. When an HTTP server gets a request initiated by the user loading remote images in an HTML formatted email, there is no way for it to identify the email.

The closest you could come would be to use unique URLs on a per email basis but that suffers from two flaws:

- It might be flagged as tracking code and used to increase the spam score of the email
- The URL can be copied by anyone with the email (including by forwarding the whole message) and reused elsewhere